# Does the compiler avoid a copy when returning a string that is taken as const reference?

Tags: c++, reference

I wander if the compiler will optimize away the copy in the following situation. I have a class whose only resource member is a string that may be a few KB large. I want to have a public member of this class to access that string and I am not sure if I should have this member returning a reference or simply by value. Suppose that I choose to return by value like so

```
class A { 
  public: 
    A();
    ~A();
    std::string getString() { return str; } 
  private:
    std::string str;
} 

int main() { 
  A *a = new A;
  const std::string& str = a->getString();
  std::cout << str;
}
```

Will the compiler optimize and avoid the copy if I take the result as a `const std::string&` as in `main`?

Comment: I don't see why you think the compiler *wouldn't* avoid a copy. The caller is asking for a ` const` reference to a string, so why wouldn't the compiler just provide exactly that?

Answer (score 2):

It's remotely possible, but is highly unlikely that the compiler will optimize away a copy in this use case.

Observe that if the copy gets optimized away, the caller's temporary essentially gets bound as a `const` reference to the object's class member. And `const` means that the referenced value cannot be changed.

With only the code shown in this question, it's possible that the compiler can prove to itself that nothing can possibly change the contents of the class member while the `const` reference remains in scope, and so it is safe to make this optimization.

But things get muddy very quickly, in a more generalized case. If there are other class methods that can potentially change the contents of the referenced class member, if there are any calls during the `const` reference's lifetime to functions or methods whose definition is not visible; the most likely result is that the compiler will have no way of knowing if it's possible for the referenced class member to be modified during the `const` reference's entire execution scope, and thus it will be forced to make a copy of the string, in order to guarantee its `const`-ness.

A compiler is free to make only those optimization that result in no visible, observed changes in a well-formed program. If the compiler cannot prove that the optimization results in no visible, observable changes then the optimization will not be performed.

P.S. Note that "modification" also includes destruction. The proposed optimization binds the `const` reference to an object in dynamic scope. If there are any intervening calls to `delete` -- explicitly or implicitly as part of calls to various library container methods -- the compiler will also have to prove to itself that the `delete`d object cannot be the object with the bound `const` reference.

Comment: Thanks, but how about if `A`'s member is also declared `const`? (I can initialize it with a delegated constructor) From your reply I infer that the compiler may optimize this copy now that it can guarantee its "constness"

Comment: I would tend to agree, subject to my P.S. -- the compiler will only have to prove that the object cannot be destroyed during the bound `const` reference's scope.

Comment: I think it's not enough. You are allowed to page out the object without actually destroying it after the copy, the compiler will have a hard time knowing what could make that happen.

Comment: The compiler doesn't need to prove that nothing *else* can change the referenced object, only to ensure that nothing does so via the `const` reference. The caller is only asking for a reference to the `string` and asserting via `const` that *it,* the caller, won't change it.